# Can't use h:commandLink inside <li> to make lazy loaded jquery tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jsf, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

i am using jquery ui tabs, and the tab content consists of some jsf code, and i want to make the tabs lazy loaded so i thought of making the tab div as panel group with default rendered=false and set render=true on click of tab link as follows:

```
<div class="tabs">
        <h:form prependId="false">
        <ul>
            <li><a id="tab1_link" href="#tab1">tab1</a></li>
            <li><a id="tab2_link" href="#tab2">tab2</a></li>
            <li>
               <h:commandLink id="tab3_link" action="#insight" value="tab3">
                 <f:ajax></f:ajax> // here will be listener 
                                   //to set the tab panel rendered to true
               </h:commandLink>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </h:form>

        <div id="tab1">
            some dynamic code here
        </div>

        <div id="tab2">
            some dynamic code here
        </div>

        <h:panelGroup id="tab3">
            some dynamic code here
        </h:panelGroup >

</div>
```

when i added h:commandLink inside the li when clicking on the command link, i can see that the whole page is loaded inside the tab, any ideas why ?

please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used instead the following example to make tabs loaded with ajax:
http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax